# What Purpose Does Array.of() Serve That An Array Literal Could Not Already?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, syntactic-sugar

The [`Array.of()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) static method — a new addition to the JavaScript spec shipped inside ECMAScript 2015 — allows one to create an array with whatever arguments are passed it. For example,

```
const exampleArr = Array.of(13, 'Test', null, 17 / 2.5, true);
// => [13, "Test", null, 6.8, true]
```

That's all good and great, but what purposes does this method expressly serve? Much of ES6 falls under the banner of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), but this doesn't really seem to apply to the `Array.of()` method given that we've always had array literals (*i.e.*, `[]`) available to us. In other words, are there specific/unique scenarios to which the method lends itself that aren't equally well served by the ordinary array literal?

Comment: It looks like it's a "prettier" form of `new Array()`.

Comment: A literal is just syntax, whereas `Array.of` is a function *value*.